# How to display the first line for a set of files(say like 10) in unix?

Tags: unix

I don't know how to do that guys.I know only how to get first line for an individual file.

First i listed only the files that has ssa as a part of its name.I used the command

```
ls | grep ssa
```

This command gives me 10 files now i want to display only the first lines for all 10 files.I don't know how to do that.Can anyone help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

The `head` command can accept multiple input files. So when you suppress the header output and limit the number of lines to 1 that should be what you are looking for:

```
head -qn 1 *
```

If you want to combine this with other commands, you have to take care to really hand over all input arguments to a call of `head`:

```
ls | xargs head -qn 1
```

Comment: Still it display only the first file name out of that 10 files.

Comment: It displays the 1 line of each file, not the file name. Probably you tried to pipe from another command without using the `xargs` utility or similar. I added an example.

Comment: Thanks,that really helped me a lot.

Comment: Welcome. Glad I could help.